# Flink job unable to connect with Openstack swift

Tags: apache-flink

We have a Flink job that needs to connect to Openstack swift for state storage using the S3 API when running in High availability mode.The image has flink-s3-fs-hadoop plugin and the flink-conf.yaml to includes following details

```
s3.path.style.access: true
s3.endpoint: <S3 endpoint Url>
s3.access-key: <swift account name>
s3.secret-key: <S3 API key>
high-availability.storageDir: s3a://<container name>/<folder name>
```

The issue is that when flink tries to connect to high-availability.storageDir, it receives a 400 Bad request response. I have also tried flink-s3-fs-presto and got the same response.Is there an additional configuration required to get it to work.

Flink Version : 1.13.6

swift version : 2.24.0.3-1.el7

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have to other required parameters for HA configured? Per https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/ha/kubernetes_ha/, I don't know if you have `high-availability` and `kubernetes.cluster-id` including your flink-conf.yaml

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes i have the following ha configurations in the flink-conf.yaml.

`high-availability: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory
 high-availability.storageDir: s3a://<container>/<folder>               restart-strategy: fixed-delay
                restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts: 3
                kubernetes.cluster-id: <cluster id>`

Comment: Can you have a look at Flink's JobManager and TaskManager logs to determine if there's relevant log information there?